# Relationship between OSIV & JPA Entity Listener @PreUpdate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, event-listener, ipreupdateeventlistener

```
User user = userRepository.findOne(1);
user.age = user.age + 1; // user.age value modify
userService.updateUser(user);
```

```
@Transactional
class UserService {
   public void updateUser(User user) {
      productRepository.findByName("AAA"); // (1)
      userRepository.save(user); // (2)
   }
}
```

```
@Entity
@EntityListener(UserListener.class)
class User {...}
```

```
class UserListener{
   @PreUpdate
   public void onPreUpdate() { ... }
}
```

When OSIV = true, 
(1) line --> **`@PreUpdate` called** / 
(2) line --> `@PreUpdate` called

When OSIV = false,
(1) line --> **`@PreUpdate` not called** / 
(2) line --> `@PreUpdate` called

*Why does this happen? Why @preupdate called when (1) line executed?*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JPA 2.0 specification:

> The PreUpdate and PostUpdate callbacks occur before and after the
>   database update operations to entity data respectively. These database
>   operations may occur at the time the entity state is updated or they
>   may occur at the time state is flushed to the database (which may be
>   at the end of the transaction).

---

Keep in mind that **@PreUpdate it will always be triggered for all read/write transactions because of the FlushMode on read/write transactions and never on readonly transactions (because of FlushMode.NEVER)**

**Without OSIV**

When you call `updateUser` , then you have a read/write transaction (the outer one) because of `@Transactional`.

Now, `findByName` is transactional but marked as *readonly* (by default all finders are *readonly*). The current transaction is suspended and a new *readonly* one is performed. That's why (1) line does not trigger `@Preupdate`.

After that, the current read/write transaction resumes (`save` is not readonly) and the `@Preupdate` is triggered.

---

**With OSIV**

This case there is only one read/write transaction bound to the current request. `findByName` is executed in a read/write transaction, therefore (1) line does trigger @Preupdate